# What is the correct way to change a string value in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Changing a mutable strings value in many languages is very easy:

```
myString = "foo"
myString = "bar"
```

However, while learning Objective C it seems like you have to really, really jump through hoops to change an existing string's value (This is often done with switch or if cases):

```
    NSMutableString *myString;
    myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"foo"];
    myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"bar"];
```

Is there an better way to change a string's value?

Comment: It might be helpful if you specified a few languages that you're comparing to rather than saying "most" languages.  I've got some familiarity with a handful of languages, and I really don't see Objective-C as being any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example

```
NSMutableString *myString;
myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"foo"];
myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"bar"];
```

the first two lines can be grouped together and the third can simply reduce to changing the `string` property of the mutable string, like this

```
NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"foo"];
myString.string = @"bar";
```

Anyway, mutable strings actually make sense only when you need to pass a reference away and allow it to be changed.

If you simply need to change the value of a `NSString *` pointer over time, just do

```
NSString *myString = @"foo";
myString = @"bar";
myString = @"baz";
```

and be done with it.

Comment: `string` is not really a _property_ of `NSMutableString`: there's no getter.

Comment: Your last example is just what I was looking for. I thought I tried it and had a problem - but it works great now.

Answer (score 3):

```
myString = @"foo"
myString = @"bar"
```

is fine in obj-c too. Don't confuse changing object value (for which you need NSMutableString) and variable value.

EDIT. Well, maybe you really need to change existing object value, but it's unclear from your question. You don't usually need to mutate existing object for `switch`es.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, I think this is the best answer, since this is the equivalent to most languages that only let you use immutable strings and seems to be part of OPs confusion

Comment: @nhgrif it was when I made the comment, oh well

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C doesn't force you to jump through any extra hoops relative to most languages.  It's probably simply less clear what you're doing in other languages perhaps, because for the most part, it's the same.

For starters, Objective-C doesn't allow objects on the stack--only on the heap.  This is true for all objects and there's nothing special about strings here.  Other languages such as C++ allow objects on the stack.

When we create objects on the heap, our variable is merely a pointer to that object, so when we create an object we have to allocate memory for it.

When we assign a string object via the `=` operator, we've change the memory location our variable points too.

You can create strings as simply as this:

```
NSString *fooString = @"foo";
NSString *barString = @"bar";
```

Which really isn't any more complex then any language I've seen.  It's just an extra `@`, how is this complicated?

CHANGING the value of a string, however, isn't so simple.  `NSString` is immutable, so to change it's value, we have to create a new object on the heap, and point to that.  We haven't changed the value, we've created a new object and pointed at that.

With `NSMutableString` however, there are a range of available methods for changing the actual value at the memory location we point to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you insist on having a string where you can change the bytes inside it or only want to replace it entirely.  Replacement of the whole thing doesn't need 'mutable' but if you'd like to replace it **and** be able to modify the bytes, then you want something like:

```
NSMutableArray *mstr = [@"foo" mutableCopy];
mstr = [@"bar" mutableCopy];
```